# Twig conditional extend layout

Tags: twig

How do I conditonally extend a twig layout template?

If it is a blog type entry, then extend layout
If it is NOT a blog type then do nothng, do not extend layout

```
{% extends entry.type == 'blog' ? '_src/pages/resource/_resourceLayout'  : '' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend or not extend from a template dynamically. A possible solution would be to create an empty template to extend from instead of the blog layout one

*main.twig*

```html
{% extends false ? 'foo.twig' : 'bar.twig' %}
{% block content %}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque pulvinar enim eu vestibulum. Morbi risus ex, gravida quis gravida quis, porttitor id purus. Etiam magna odio, maximus dapibus turpis eget, porttitor luctus tortor. Cras auctor nisi et nunc condimentum sagittis. Sed lobortis mi nibh, euismod posuere lectus porttitor non.
{% endblock %}
```

*foo.twig*

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <h1>Foo</h1>
        <p>
            {% block content %}

            {% endblock %}
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

*bar.twig*

```html
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ezsxo3)